# When Forward Secrecy ciphers are used, the Torproject website uses 1024 bit key exchange; Can this be improved?

Tags: encryption, tls, https, web-hosting

While the website of Torproject uses a 2048 bit certificate, if Forward Secrecy ciphers are used, the key exchange is only 1024 bit:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=torproject.org

EDIT: This is a question to ask people of the Torproject to change the DHE keysize.

Comment: I don't believe this is the place for suggestions. perhaps this will help "tor-talk@lists.torproject.org is for all discussion about theory, design, development, and use of Onion Routing. tor-dev@lists.torproject.org is for Tor research and development. For both of these [mailing lists](https://www.torproject.org/docs/documentation.html.en#MailingLists), you must subscribe before you can post."

Comment: If you don't want to post on mailinglists I'd suggest to add a ticket to [Tor's trac](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor).